# Error at line 1, col 1: Unexpected character "<" in Apex oracle

Tags: json, oracle, parsing, plsql, oracle-apex

when I send a file to another database, I get a response, I parse it with the command `apex_json.parse (v_clob_post);` and write down the change I need. But there is an error that I cannot resolve:

> ORA-20987: Error at line 1, col 1: Unexpected character" <"

How can I solve this?

My code:

```
set serveroutput on
Declare     
v_clob_post     CLOB;
v_clob          CLOB;
l_body_b        BLOB;
g_EXTERNAL_ID  varchar2(300);   
v_count int;
BEGIN 

  for r in (select id from SEC_OBJECT)

  loop  

    select MYFILE INTO l_body_b from SEC_OBJECT  where id = r.id;
    apex_json.initialize_clob_output;
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('snapshot', blob_to_clob_base64(l_body_b)); 
    apex_json.close_object;
    V_clob  := apex_json.get_clob_output;
    apex_json.free_output;
   if   l_body_b is not null then
                    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';  
                    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';  
                    v_clob_post  := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'myURL',p_http_method => 'POST'
                    ,p_body =>  v_clob );
   if apex_web_service.g_status_code != 200 then
      dbms_output.put_line('id ' || r.id || ' status ' || apex_web_service.g_status_code);
      dbms_output.put_line(v_clob_post);
    else
      apex_json.parse(v_clob_post);     
    end;


 apex_json.parse(v_clob_post);     
 g_EXTERNAL_ID := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'id_document'); 
 update SEC_OBJECT set EXTERNAL_ID = g_EXTERNAL_ID where id = r.id;
    end if;
end loop;
end;
/
```

My answer (JSON I’m parsing):

```
successful: true
id_document: "112118e18"
```

Comment: There's no `<` in your code so ... probably it is somewhere else. Enable debugging and run the page again. Once you hit the error, review debug info - maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks for suggesting my question, can i evaluate my code is it ok ?? I mean, can it be a problem? This code has worked perfectly so far! And today such a flashback appeared (

Comment: What changed since "so far"? I'm afraid I can't help much.

Comment: @Littlefoot first, I used this code in the second workspace, secondly, this code worked when I set the conditions for the loop made for r in (select id from SEC_OBJECT where id <1500) (250 entries), and only when I set the conditions for the loop for r in (select id from SEC_OBJECT where id> 1500) (1800 entries) he gave this error! . And these changes can not affect the performance, right ???

Comment: If number of results returned is now increased, maybe there's something wrong with that. I see you use CLOBs (which is OK), except for G_EXTERNAL_ID variable. Should you increase its size, perhaps?

Comment: @Littlefoot I increased to 2000 characters, but it not helped

Comment: No further ideas, sorry.

Comment: If the exception is being thrown by the `apex_json.parse(v_clob_post)` call then the `v_clob_post` doesn't contain valid JSON. You need to debug what that value actually is when the error occurs. Presumably the response from the REST call is OK for most of them, but for one or more IDs the `v_clob` you send is resulting in an unusual response.

Comment: From a quick web search you might also get something useful from `apex_web_service.g_status_code` immediately after the `make_rest_request` call. The API you're calling might be returning an HTML error page instead of the JSON you expect; looking at that would still be useful, but the error code might tell you something.

Comment: @AlexPoole can you help me reproduce this in the code ?? when i add, an error occurs!

Comment: @AlexPoole i added "dbms_output.put_line ('g_status_code =' || apex_web_service.g_status_code);" but it didn't help, i don't see the details of the error, but can this code so when this error appears, i saw what exactly came to me ???? what text ???

Comment: Does your client have output enabled? (e.g. `set serveroutput on`, but you might be using a GUI/IDE). You can `dbms_output.put_line(v_clob_post);` too. Both of those *before* the parse call, obviously... You might want to include the current `r.id` in those so you can see which row it has a problem on.

Answer (score 3):

It appears one of the REST calls you are making results in an error on the server end, and the response you get has an HTML error page instead of JSON data.

To help you identify what you are getting back and which call is causing a problem, add debugging to your code, e.g.:

```
set serveroutput on

Declare     
...
BEGIN 

for r in (select id from SEC_OBJECT where id >1500)
  loop  
...
    v_clob_post  := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'http://myURL',p_http_method => 'POST'
      ,p_body =>  v_clob );

    dbms_output.put_line('id ' || r.id || ' status ' || apex_web_service.g_status_code);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_clob_post);

    apex_json.parse(v_clob_post);     
...
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Depending on your client you might need to do something else to see the output; `set serveroutput on` will work in SQL*Plus, SQLcl and SQL Developer (if run as a script), the latter also has a "View->Dbms Output" menu to open another window, others will have their own equivalents.

You may be able to reduce the output, and narrow the problem, by doing:

```
    v_clob_post  := ...

    if apex_web_service.g_status_code != 200 then
      dbms_output.put_line('id ' || r.id || ' status ' || apex_web_service.g_status_code);
      dbms_output.put_line(v_clob_post);
    else
      apex_json.parse(v_clob_post);     
    end;
```

Hopefully the status and response will tell you why it didn't like that particularly `v_clob` request.

Comment: I added but an error "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Comment: @Apex_MAN - whatever client you're using doesn't recognise `set serveroutput on`, so remove that line, and use the client's native controls to enable that output. How you do that depends on which client you're actually using.